# Convert public key string to pem format with python

Tags: python, rsa, public-key, pem

I have the following string in python:

```
pubkey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsFWkb/eSl6I3DRVhaonW3DFy8EnL0yaPiDzCcOLuYfBjN9zZIR1wXmnMJFle1K89qHGg42wgweVTIwA1XFTfoUKSziwsjF6FscZX5H56ZYyS/wWiO3rWWynlfbSZt+ga71+ndsu+A0Dy7Nn7ZgP8kRsu4UM5vE7QQTRERNiUKpzScN1cgZUFUqSddQmkwTEN8hH1mFX1Mum54NGqWIlmQxQDrOyogmMXIaaakhabcmuIPMULVVDVwUJC9sSDsc/j05qcZn3kkiEBRyiYB6ZLY2W7WfiV+dB7/icPONsYSD0FxHWEGNnbqtiGoNf9WZWtaP+o8WMR9sB3GKGVnbLvbQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

I would like to know how can I convert it to pem format in order to use `RSA.importKey(pubkey)`

I need to be able to manipulate the variable pubkey, because its data could be dynamically changed by the user, so I can't just change the string data.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `PyCryptodome`? If so, isn't it `import_key`?

Comment: We'd need more information about what error you faced when you imported the existing PEM encoded string? If you received an `RSA Key format error`, it's probably because you don't have the `\n` delimiters in your string

Comment: With PEM encoding header and footer are in separate lines and regarding the Base64 encoded body there is a line break after every 64 characters. For `importKey()` it is sufficient if header and footer are in separate lines. `importKey()` and `import_key()` work both.